# Fan switch compatibility

Tags: switch, fans, dimmer-switch, ceiling-fan

How do I determine if I need to use a manufacturer's fan switch or if I can use an off-the-shelf fan switch?

E.g. I would like to buy an [Emerson Loft fan](http://ceilingfans.emerson.com/shop/en/fan/loft-fan-cf765ww) and [Emerson Curva fan](http://ceilingfans.emerson.com/shop/en/fan/52-curva-sky-fan-cf152ww) and control them with [Lagrange Adorne paddle fan controls](http://www.legrand.us/adorne/products/dimmers/aafn4s16am4.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the specifications, both the Emerson Loft Fan CF765WW and Emerson CF144/CF152 Curva Fan appear to use PSC motors, so they should be compatible with any typical fan speed control, including the Lagrand AAFN4S16AM4.

I notice that both of these fans are premium models that have the speed controls included in the box.  In the case of the Curva, the package includes a wireless remote and receiver.

Obviously you won't be saving any money by using "off-the-shelf" fan switches with these.